# Как вставить изображение в QLabel, с возможностью изменения размера изображения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qpixmap

[image: как вставить в этот класс]

Как сделать картинку, которую мы вставляем в `label` при помощи `Pixmap` саморастягивающеся?

То есть, мы вставляем картинку в `Label`, при этом `Label` обретает размеры картинки. Потом окно приложения развертываем на полный экран и картинка в `label`, как была того размера, так и осталась.

Еще, нельзя изменить размер окна меньше чем размер `label`.
Мне надо, чтобы картинка при развертывании полного экрана картинка увеличилась **`пропорционально`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то один из возможных вариантов может выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class DisplayArea(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._flag = False
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;")

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.scale_image()

    def scale_image(self):
        if self.pix_map.isNull():
            return
        scaled = self.pix_map.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(scaled)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if not self._flag:
            self._flag = True
            self.scale_image()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: setattr(self, "_flag", False))
        super().resizeEvent(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    da = DisplayArea()
    da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"))
    w.setCentralWidget(da)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> как можно обойтись без того, чтобы не делать его центральным виджетом?

Попробуйте так:

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    da = DisplayArea()
    da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"))

#    w.setCentralWidget(da)
#    w.show()
    da.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Но как можно добавить это в другой класс все также без добавления, как центрального виджета?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class DisplayArea(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._flag = False
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;")

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.scale_image()

    def scale_image(self):
        if self.pix_map.isNull():
            return
        scaled = self.pix_map.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(scaled)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if not self._flag:
            self._flag = True
            self.scale_image()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: setattr(self, "_flag", False))
        super().resizeEvent(e)

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('PqQT5 Pixmap')

        da = DisplayArea()
        da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"))
        self.setCentralWidget(da)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы равнение картинки виджета было посередине?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class DisplayArea(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._flag = False
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
        self.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;")

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.pix_map = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.scale_image()

    def scale_image(self):
        if self.pix_map.isNull():
            return
        scaled = self.pix_map.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(scaled)

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        if not self._flag:
            self._flag = True
            self.scale_image()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: setattr(self, "_flag", False))
        super().resizeEvent(e)

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        da = DisplayArea()
        da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"))
        da.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)  
        self.grid.addWidget(da, 1, 0, 10, 10) 

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('PqQT5 Pixmap')        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Отлично!
Вопрос по коду...
что делает...scale_image(self) и resizeEvent(self, e)...

Comment: И теперь это можно использовать с другими виджетами?

Comment: Метод `scale_image(self)` - устанавливает изображение метки, масштабируя его до заданного размера, 
используя соотношение сторон и режимы преобразования.

`resizeEvent(self, e)` - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

Comment: как можно обойтись без того, чтобы не делать его центральным виджетом?

Comment: я добавил в ответ свое предложение

Comment: Спасибо!
Но как можно добавить это в другой класс все также без добавления, как центрального виджета?

Comment: я добавил картинку в описание

Comment: я добавил в ответ свое предложение

Comment: То есть он в классе обязательно должен быть центральным виджетом?

Comment: я уже не понимаю, что вам надо сделать. Давайте вы сформируете новый вопрос, приведете свой пример кода (только не на картинке), опишите что вы хотите и что у вас не получается - вам объязательно помогут.

Comment: Только вопрос опять с вашим кодом...
Можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы равнение картинки виджета было посередине?

Comment: Я добавил свой ответ, который делает, что мне надо.

Comment: Разобрался...
добавил строку...self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
в метод init_ui(self)

Comment: Добавил последнее обновление по этому вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!)

Comment: Еще такой вопрос...
при повторном вызове(при смене картинки)....da.set_image(QtGui.QImage("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"))
картинка не меняется...
что делать?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Спасибо огромное за всю помощь, предоставленную мне с этим вопросом!]

Спасибо огромное за всю помощь, предоставленную мне с этим вопросом!

Информация помогла мне разобраться с этой проблемой.